# Showing angles around plot in matlab / octave

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I can create a plot with pol2cart but how can I get the angles to show up at the end off the lines?  See code below:

```
hold on ;
    for angle =  0:20:(360-20)
        [x1,y1] = pol2cart(  angle / 180 * pi , [0 2]);
        plot(x1,y1,'r')
    end

    for rho  =  0:0.1:2
        [x1,y1] = pol2cart(  0:0.01:2*pi , rho);
        plot(x1,y1,'b')
    end
    axis equal
```

[image]

I'm trying to get the angle increments to show up all around see image below.
Please note I didn't draw all the numbered angles just the first couple to show what I'm trying to do

PS: I'm using octave 3.8.1 which tries to use the same language syntax as matlab
[image: Imgae2]

Comment: And for the reference: With the Octave 4.2 release (current development branch) you can just use "polar": http://www.tech-chat.de/compare_plot_demos/fltk/polar_01.png, http://www.tech-chat.de/compare_plot_demos/fltk/polar_03.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like

```
step = 20;

r= 2.2;
for idx = 0:step:360-step
    text(r*cos(pi*idx/180),r*sin(pi*idx/180),num2str(idx), ...
        'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'color',[1 .5 0])
end
```

For a better fit, include

```
axis(1.05*[-r r -r r])
axis equal
```

(This works for MATLAB, I dont know if the syntax is exactly the same in Octave.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the information and plot animated

```
%polar_chart_with_angles and there opposites
clear all, clc, clf
%find how many angles to make one full cycleremeber to divide by two if using stereo signal 180 out of phase
incr=72;
angle_wanted=incr;

n = lcm(360, 180 - angle_wanted) / (180 - angle_wanted)
angle_div=[0:incr:incr*n] %angle divsions
angle_div_mod=mod(angle_div,360) %angle divsions mod into 360
angle_div_mod_opp=mod(angle_div+180,360) %oppsite angle divsions mod into 360

%for circles
r= 2.2;
for rho  =  0:0.1:2
    [x1,y1] = pol2cart(  0:0.01:2*pi , rho);
    plot(x1,y1,'b')
    axis(1.10*[-r r -r r])
    axis equal
    hold on;
end

%for orig angles

for ii=1:n
    angle=angle_div(ii)
    [x1,y1] = pol2cart(  angle / 180 * pi , [0 2]);
    plot(x1,y1,'r')
    hold on;
    title_h=title(['Norig= ', int2str(ii)]);
    %title_h = title('This is the title');
    set(title_h, 'Position', [0.5, 0.02],'VerticalAlignment', 'bottom', 'HorizontalAlignment', 'left')
    %%for creating orig angles
    idx=angle_div_mod(ii);
    text(r*cos(pi*idx/180),r*sin(pi*idx/180),num2str(idx), 'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'color',[1 .5 0])
    pause (.1)
end

%for oppsite angles
for ii=1:n
    angle_opp=angle_div_mod_opp(ii)
    [x1,y1] = pol2cart(  angle_opp/ 180 * pi , [0 2]);
    plot(x1,y1,'g')
    hold on;
    title(['Nopp= ', int2str(ii)]);
    %for creating oppsite angles
    idx=angle_div_mod_opp(ii);
    text(r*cos(pi*idx/180),r*sin(pi*idx/180),num2str(idx), 'HorizontalAlignment','center', 'color',[.5 .7 .7])
    pause (.1)
end
```

[image]